# Writing mathematical equation in jupyter notebook in a markdown (.md) file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gitlab, latex, markdown

I have written a document in the jupyter notebook as a markdown (.md) file. The document contains some mathematical equation which I have written inside `$$ equation $$`, for example,

```
$$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$
```

Now, when I push the .md file in the Gitlab, my equations are appearing in the latex format, like
**$$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$**

The file was okay when I did the print preview but in the GitLab the equations are appearing inside `$$...$$`.

Could you pls help me to resolve the issue?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to resolve the issue. Most of the solutions are mentioned in the below link in the math section
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html

To summarise

1. This math is inline `` $`a^2+b^2=c^2`$ ``
2. This is on a separate line

   ````
   ```math
   a^2+b^2=c^2
   ```
   ````
3. Separate line with equation number

   ````
   ```math
   \tag{1} a^2+b^2=c^2
   ```
   ````

Now, I am trying to find how to add \label{} in the equation.